# Error while trying to activate environment in Miniconda prompt

Tags: miniconda

This is the command and error:

```
(base) C:\Users\Aaditya Singh\Desktop\ML_Sample_Project>conda activate C:\Users\'Aaditya Singh'\Desktop\ML_Sample_Project\env
activate does not accept more than one argument:
["C:\\Users\\'Aaditya", "Singh'\\Desktop\\ML_Sample_Project\\env"]
```

Comment: You need to put quotes around the whole path, not just your name.

Comment: Thanks you very much...it soved the problem